# How to use session entity in dialogflow's inline editor?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

My problem is passing parameters between intents' hooks.

As example: at one hook I made a request for my own backend and receive a *sessionId*. I need pass the *sessionId* to an another intent for second request in it's hook.

How I can do it? I can't find any examples, documentations or best practices.

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with *contexts*.

In your first intent you do something like this:

```
function firstIntentHandler(agent){
  return axios.get(`https://yourserver.com`)
   .then(function (response)  {
    agent.add(response.data.sessionId);

    const context = {'name': 'yourcontextname', 'lifespan': 3, 'parameters': 
                     {'sessionid': response.data.sessionId }}; 
    agent.setContext(context);

        }).catch(function (error) {
    agent.add("An error occured.");
  });
}
```

*sessionId* is the variable name in your json data sent by your server.

In your other intent you can access this data like this:

```
function otherIntentHandler(agent) {
  const context = agent.getContext("yourcontextname");
  const sessionid = context.parameters.sessionid;
  // do something with this session id
  });
}
```

Be careful with camelcase for your context name. I have the feeling that uppercase letters are stored as lowercase...